Relation between Saab B3LA concept aircraft and AMX International
The Saab B3LA aircraft concept and the AMX aircraft were developed around the same time and out of similar requirements.
According to the Swedish Wikipedia:

The [B3LA] project was abandoned in 1979 in favor of the Saab 39 Gripen, without any prototype being completed. The project was partly a collaboration with Aermacchi. When Sweden pulled out of the project, Aermacchi found a new partner in Brazilian Embraer and their AMX aircraft is largely built on the basic design from the B3LA.

(My translation)
This is given without any reference. I can also find this "fact" in other places on the internet, without references.
Was the AMX actually a continuation of the B3LA or are the designs similar because of similar requirements and the available techology at that time?

I can't find anything even on Italian sources related to the participation of Aermacchi to the B3LA project.

Also, AMX started in 1978, one year before the cancellation of the B3LA which would be strange if it's the same project. I suspect that the wikipedia sentence may be incorrect or speculation.
